# stock value in vb.net variable

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net-2010

please I have the following vb.net 2010 and MYSQL and I used disconnected mode.

I want to do

```
dim value1 as int = (select count(*) from table)
```

How can I create a dataset and excute the sql query in disconnected mode?

Thnanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
dim value1 as int

using connection as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(YOURCONNECTIONSTRING)
connection.open
using command as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select count(*) AS QTY from table", connection)
using reader as SqlReader = command.ExecuteReader()
value1 = reader.getInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("QTY"))
End Using
end Using
End Using
```